Fetching API/JSON For A NextJS Application
I am creating a NextJs website related to crop disease detection which sends photo and environmental factors to a fastapi python server where the data gets processed and then display that in a component of my app. More specifically generate text prompt on the basis of that data using Mistral AI API and show that in component. The data is successfully processed and sent as json on a GET link at localhost:8000/final. My site is not able to show that data in that component although get request is going. I have even tried a test file to check what's going on. It shows undefined on console and Error loading data on UI.
This is prediction_server.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import io
from PIL import Image
import geocoder
import openmeteo_requests
import requests_cache
import pandas as pd
from retry_requests import retry
import joblib

def get_current_location():
    g = geocoder.ip('me')
    return g.latlng

# Get current location
location = get_current_location()
if location:
    print(f"Latitude: {location[0]}, Longitude: {location[1]}")
else:
    print("Unable to determine the location.")

# Set up caching and retry mechanisms for weather data requests
cache_session = requests_cache.CachedSession('.cache', expire_after=3600)
retry_session = retry(cache_session, retries=5, backoff_factor=0.2)
openmeteo = openmeteo_requests.Client(session=retry_session)

# Define weather API parameters
url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast"
params = {
    "latitude": location[0],
    "longitude": location[1],
    "current_weather": True,
}

# Fetch weather data
responses = openmeteo.weather_api(url, params=params)
response = responses[0]

# Extract current weather variables
current = response.Current()
current_temperature_2m = current.Variables(0).Value()
current_relative_humidity_2m = current.Variables(1).Value()
current_precipitation = current.Variables(2).Value()
current_wind_speed_10m = current.Variables(3).Value()

# Load models and encoders
pipeline = joblib.load('linear_regression_model.pkl')
encoder_severity = joblib.load('encoder_severity.pkl')
encoder_fertilizer = joblib.load('encoder_fertilizer.pkl')
load_disease_classification_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('disease_classification_model.h5')

# Define FastAPI app
app = FastAPI()

# Define labels for disease classification
labels = {
    0: 'Apple Scab',
    1: 'Apple Black Rot',
    2: 'Cedar Apple Rust',
    3: 'Healthy Apple',
    4: 'Healthy Blueberry',
    5: 'Cherry Powdery Mildew',
    6: 'Healthy Cherry',
    7: 'Corn Cercospora Leaf Spot',
    8: 'Maize Common Rust',
    9: 'Corn Northern Leaf Blight',
    10: 'Healthy Corn',
    11: 'Grape Black Rot',
    12: 'Grape Black Measles',
    13: 'Grape Leaf Blight',
    14: 'Healthy Grape',
    15: 'Orange Citrus Greening',
    16: 'Peach Bacterial Spot',
    17: 'Healthy Peach',
    18: 'Pepper Bell Bacterial Spot',
    19: 'Healthy Pepper Bell',
    20: 'Potato Early Blight',
    21: 'Potato Late Blight',
    22: 'Healthy Potato',
    23: 'Healthy Raspberry',
    24: 'Healthy Soybean',
    25: 'Squash Powdery Mildew',
    26: 'Strawberry Leaf Scorch',
    27: 'Healthy Strawberry',
    28: 'Tomato Bacterial Spot',
    29: 'Tomato Early Blight',
    30: 'Tomato Late Blight',
    31: 'Tomato Leaf Mold',
    32: 'Tomato Septoria Leaf Spot',
    33: 'Tomato Spider Mites',
    34: 'Tomato Target Spot',
    35: 'Tomato Yellow Leaf Curl Virus',
    36: 'Tomato Mosaic Virus',
    37: 'Healthy Tomato'
}

# Predict the disease class from an image
def predict_image(model, img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img_array = np.array(img) / 255.0
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    preds = model.predict(img_array)
    predicted_class = labels[np.argmax(preds[0])]
    return predicted_class

# Global variable to store the final prediction
final_prediction = {}

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    image_stream = io.BytesIO(contents)
    img = Image.open(image_stream).convert("RGB")

    # Predict the disease using the model
    disease_prediction = predict_image(load_disease_classification_model, img)

    # Prepare input data for severity and fertilizer prediction
    input_data = [disease_prediction, current_temperature_2m, current_relative_humidity_2m, current_precipitation, current_wind_speed_10m]
    input_df = pd.DataFrame([input_data], columns=['Class', 'Temperature (°C)', 'Humidity (%)', 'Precipitation (mm)', 'Wind Speed (m/s)'])
    prediction = pipeline.predict(input_df)

    # Extract predictions
    severity_encoded = prediction[0, :encoder_severity.categories_[0].size]
    severity_percentage = prediction[0, encoder_severity.categories_[0].size]
    fertilizer_encoded = prediction[0, encoder_severity.categories_[0].size + 1:-1]
    fertilizer_amount = prediction[0, -1]

    # Decode categorical predictions
    severity = encoder_severity.inverse_transform([severity_encoded])[0][0]
    fertilizer = encoder_fertilizer.inverse_transform([fertilizer_encoded])[0][0]

    # Store the final prediction globally
    global final_prediction
    final_prediction = {
        'Disease Prediction': disease_prediction,
        'Severity': severity,
        'Severity Percentage': severity_percentage,
        'Fertilizer': fertilizer,
        'Fertilizer Amount (kg/acre)': fertilizer_amount
    }

    return final_prediction

@app.get("/final")
async def final_output():
    return JSONResponse(content=final_prediction)


this is fetchdata.tsx
import Image from "next/image";

export default function FetchData({ myprops }) {
    console.log("Props received:", myprops); // Debug: Check what is logged

    if (!myprops || Object.keys(myprops).length === 0) {
        return <div>Error loading data</div>; // Handle the case where myprops is null or undefined
    }

    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            <div>{JSON.stringify(myprops, null, 2)}</div> {/* Display the JSON data */}
        </main>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/final');
        
        // Check if the response is successful
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        
        const myprops = await response.json();
        console.log("Fetched data:", myprops); // Debug: Check what is logged
        
        return {
            props: { myprops } // Pass myprops directly to the FetchData component
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        return {
            props: { myprops: null } // Handle errors gracefully
        };
    }
}


On console its showing undefined while using postman it shows
{
    "Disease Prediction": "Apple Scab",
    "Severity": "Mild",
    "Severity Percentage": 63.3072989388162,
    "Fertilizer": "Potash",
    "Fertilizer Amount (kg/acre)": 29.951552986003108
}

and by using curl http://localhost:8000/final it shows
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Disease Prediction":"Apple Scab","Severity":"Mild","Severity
                    Percentage":63.3072989388162,"Fertilizer":"Potash","Fertilizer Amount
                    (kg/acre)":29.951552986003108}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 163
                    Content-Type: application/json
                    Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2024 14:45:36 GMT
                    Server: uvicorn

                    {"Disease Prediction":"Apple Scab","Severity":"Mild","Severity Percentage"...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 163], [Content-Type, application/json], [Date, Thu, 29 Aug 2024 14:45:36 GMT],
                    [Server, uvicorn]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 163

But not even a GET request is going when i use fetchdata.tsx

If I had to guess, it would be due to CORS not being enabled. Preflight requests are OPTION method types not GET.

Can you explain more and how to fix it ?
